# Firefox 5 - infinite loop handling

Tags: javascript, firefox, browser

During recent development I've discovered infinite loop in application I'm working on.
First error I got was while using FF4, and later I've done same test in IE8 and FF3.6.
Now, even that I've noticed that IE8 is throwing exception (error popup with stop script button) much faster than FF4, the error was always thrown by both browsers for that error.

After upgrading FF4 to FF5 I noticed something that could be quite a problem for developers.
FF5 is stopping/breaking infinite loop, and continue to work without noticing the user.
I'm not sure if I bump on some weird behavior, and I'd like someone to confirm (before I drop FF5 from my dev tools).

Comment: I get the same "A script is busy" dialog in Firefox 5 that previous versions had.

Comment: You most likely checked "Don't ask me again" in the popup window

Comment: No.
But if I did this might help
http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/questions/755701

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just tried it directly in the bar and got the below warning.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.
Now, I can confirm that this one is working for me too, but when I try what Anthony wrote, it never stops (need to kill it from task manager).

Probably there's some problem with my installation. I'll reinstall it to check if that helps.

Comment: Well, I don't know what was the problem but after reinstalling FF5 it's working almost fine. Now it never breaks the loop, but sometimes it doesn't throw exception and CPU usage goes to 100% so I need to kill the process.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the following script:

```
<script>

var i = 0, j = 0;
console.log(i);
console.log(j);
while(i < 1) {
    j++;
}
console.log(j);

</script>
```

in Firefox 5 and got a confirm dialog notifying me of a potential infinite loop, and asking whether or not I wanted to stop the script.